# sql - How to group by month when finding maximum marks of that month?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have *student_mark* table which has *date*, *mark*, *student_id* column.
I want to find max(mark) of each month of all students.

I am doing this:

```
select max(mark),exam_dt 
from student_mark  
where month(exam_dt) = 04 or month(exam_dt) = 05 or month(exam_dt) = 06 
group by exam_dt;
```

but i am getting this.
It is grouping by individual date and not the month.
It should display the maximum marks of a month.

---

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 2):

Just change your query to `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` the month i.e.

```
select max(mark), month(exam_dt)
from student_mark  
where month(exam_dt) = 04 or month(exam_dt) = 05 or month(exam_dt) = 06 
group by month(exam_dt);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `in` instead of `or` and also use `month` function in group by

```
select max(mark),month(exam_dt)
from student_mark  
where month(exam_dt) in (04,05,06) 
group by month(exam_dt);
```

Comment: @SamD82 if someone answer helps in SO please accept his answer

Answer (score 0):

You have some different ways for example you can do it like this :

```
select max(mark),exam_month from
    (select mark,month(exam_dt) as exam_month from student_mark)
     where exam_month = 04 or exam_month = 05 or exam_month = 06 group by exam_month;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is rarely interesting to look at months independent of years. It is in fact dangerous to disregard the year in the real world.

I would start with:

```
select year(exam_dt) as yyyy, month(exam_dt) as mm, max(mark)
from student_mark  
where month(exam_dt) in (4, 5, 6) 
group by year(exam_dt), month(exam_dt);
```

If you are only interested in 2017, then your query should be explicit:

```
select month(exam_dt) as mm, max(mark)
from student_mark  
where exam_dte >= '2017-04-01' and exam_dt < '2017-07-01'
group by month(exam_dt);
```

Note that I changed the `where` clause to compare actual dates.  This is another best practice.  The use of functions on columns can impede the optimizer and make the query slower than it otherwise would be.